# Can't able to fetch the user location in meteor

Tags: meteor, geolocation, reversegeocodelocation

I developed a meteor app in which while registering I am fetching the user location at the client side, to do so I have added the packages listed below:

```
meteor add mdg:geolocation    
meteor add jeremy:geocomplete    
meteor aldeed:geocoder    
meteor add jaymc:google-reverse-geocode
```

The code written at client side is as follows:

```
  if (Meteor.isClient) { 

  Meteor.startup(() => {
  GoogleMaps.load({
   v: '3.26',
   key: '',                                   
  libraries: 'geometry,places'
  });
 console.log("is GoogleMaps.loaded",GooglMaps.loaded());
 });

   Template.Registration.onRendered(function () {
      Tracker.autorun(() => {
        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {

           $('#txt_address').geocomplete({country: "AU", type: 
           ['()']});

            }      
          });
       var date = new Date();
      $('#div_dob').datetimepicker({ 
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        maxDate : date,
        ignoreReadonly: true

       });
      date=null;
     });

    Template.Registration.helpers({
      location:function(){
       $('input[name="txt_address"]').val(Session.get('location'));
     }
    });

     Template.Registration.events({
      'click #btn_findlocation':function(event){
         alert('Find Location')
        event.preventDefault();
        function success(position) {
        var crd = position.coords;
        console.log(`Latitude0 : ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Longitude0: ${crd.longitude}`);
        var lat = crd.latitude;
        var long = crd.longitude;
        reverseGeocode.getLocation(lat, long, function(location)
        {           
   console.log("Address",JSON.stringify(reverseGeocode.getAddrStr()));
         Session.set('location', reverseGeocode.getAddrStr());
          });

          };// end of function success(position)

        function error(err) {
           console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message); 
        };//end of function error(err) 

     // geolocation options
        var options = {
         enableHighAccuracy: true,
         maximumAge: 0
          };// end of  var options

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, 
         options);

        },

      })

    }
```

But I am getting false value for GoogleMaps.loaded() function and the following below error when I click a button to fetch the location.

> Can't able to read formatted address of undefined.

[image]

Results are inconsistent as sometimes I was able to fetch the location other times not.

Please give any suggestions...

Comment: Please add the code you wrote and the error output as formatted text here (instead of linking it). Otherwise this will we hard to determine what is causing your error

Comment: Hi,I have edited my question..Can you have a look at it@Jankapunkt